# C# Upload a zip file of two files to FTP based on two strings without being able to save anywhere

Tags: c#, azure, ftp, zip

I have to upload a zip file based on two csv files themselves constrcuted in code.
I used to have a server where I generated my two csv files into a folder and then I zipped the folder and then I uploaded the zip file to ftp.
But now I'm migrating that job into a Windows azure clud service worker.

So the question is how to reach the same finality without being able to save intermediary files anywhere? I'm trying to look into Streams but without success so far.

Comment: Just curious: Why you don't want to save the contents on a folder in VM? You could just use the same approach you had earlier.

Comment: Because I'm totally new to Windows azure :-) In my portal I see "default folder". Is this a folder I can access to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by the "default folder" in your portal but to answer your question, the approach for zipping files would be more or less the same as you would do on your local server. You just have to remember one thing: On your local server you could create the folder anywhere and then put csv files there for zipping. In Windows Azure, this would not work.

You would have to make use of `Local Storage`. So what you would do is create a folder in local storage, write CSV files there and then zip them. You may find this link useful for local storage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee758708.aspx.

Comment: That's what I found meanwhile :-)http://blog.codingoutloud.com/2011/06/12/azure-faq-can-i-write-to-the-file-system-on-windows-azure/